# I am trying to code a random Adjective generator using Python

Tags: python

I am trying to code in Python something like a random "**adjectif generator**" using the letters of a name (input). For example, if you enter a name let's say "PETER", the result and print will be like: "P" for Perfect, "E" as in Elegant, "T" for Tall etc....

I started my code below:

```
#name = input("Enter your name here: ")
name = "Peter"
for i in name:
    if i == "Peter":
        print(i + " ... For Pretty")
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! What is your specific question? Is there an error with your code, a wrong output, are you stuck with a particular difficulty? Stackoverflow questions should be specific and answerable, other than just "can someone tell me how to write my code". For example, in your code above I would recommend changing `if i == "Peter":` to `if i == "P":`

Comment: You can do preprocessing like probably make use of dictionary where you can store key-value like P for perfect, E for elegant and using that you can print such thing. It's probably easiest way for novice.

Comment: yes @aryasingh i think you are right but how can i loop/ iterate/loop through the multiple dictionaries, using an IF statement? 
adjectives = { goodAdj : {'A': 'Angel', 'B':'Beauty', 'C':'Cool'}, oppAdj : {'A': 'Angel', 'B':'Beauty', 'C':'Cool'}, funnyAdj: {'A': 'Angel', 'B':'Beauty', 'C':'Cool'} }
name = input("Enter your name here: ")

Comment: @sngvfx Well the simplest answer is by storing and accessing. Let me show you what i mean. Store value of d['goodAdj'] in some variable then use that variable to access . Ex var = d['goodAdj'] then var['A']

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to build a database of adjectives. Then in your script, loop over each letter of the provided name and retrieve an adjective for that letter.

```
def GetAdjectiveFromDatabase(letter):
  #todo implement an adjective database
  return "Perfect"

#name = input("Enter your name here: ")
name = "Peter"
for i in name:
  adjective = GetAdjectiveFromDatabase(i)
  print("%s is for %s" % (i,adjective))
```

Comment: Can I build a dictionary for the adjective's database? So in this case I create like 26 adjectives (26 letters of the alphabet) and then access the dictionary with indexes. for example >>> adjectives = {A: 'Awesome', B: 'Beautiful', C: 'Charming', D: 'Devil'} etc.....
 
then accessing the dictionary  

>>> if adjectives[A]
'Awesome'
>>> adjectives[C]
'Charming'  etc....

Comment: You certainly could do that. And you wouldn't need all the conditional logic. Just

`return adjectiveDict[letter]`

However, then it's not really 'random' because you'll always get the same adjective for each letter. I think it'd be more interesting to have some randomness so that you can get different results with the same string.

Comment: Yeah i am new in Python so i am using baby steps lol (things i think I know so far).... what about i created multiple dictionaries (for good adjectives like "cool", "angel" etc VS bad/opposite adjectives like "devilish" etc... so the logic will be  adjectives = { goodAdj : {A, B, C}, oppAdj : {A, B, C,}, funnyAdj: {A,B,C} } then iterate/loop through the multiple dictionaries.... not sure if this makes sense...

Comment: You could that, then you'd need some condition to determine when to select from which dictionary. Still seems like the best solution would be a database with a column to hold the word and another to determine its type (i.e. good, bad, funny, insulting)